TypeScript Error: "The types of 'msGraphClientFactory.getClient' are incompatible" during SPFx gulp bundle
I am working on a SharePoint Framework (SPFx) project, and when I run the gulp bundle in my project, I get the following TypeScript error:

[15:01:43] [tsc] The types of 'msGraphClientFactory.getClient' are incompatible between these types.
[15:01:43] [tsc] Type '(version: "3") => Promise' is not assignable to type '() => Promise'.
error TS2322: Type 'WebPartContext' is not assignable to type 'ISPFXContext'.


Can you get around the problem by casting as per Ivan the Bearable? If not, can you include some code into the question.
